# jQuery .not() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently met a problem with .not() function, this is the code:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('.test').not('.updated').each(function(){
                var $parentDiv = $('.test').parent('div');
                // do something
                parentDiv.find('.test').addClass("updated"); 
                //Above: change this element's status
        });
}, 3000);
```

Problem is:
Sometimes when the element $('.test') who has class 'updated' also within the loop.

What I think:
***it means the not() selector not working?***

So I would like to know what is REALLY the problem of the code?

Comment: Have you nested `test` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is finding all the elements with class "test", and then excluding those that also have the class "updated".

Then, for each of those elements, you're doing *another* `.find()` operation to find elements with class "test". That, however, does not include the `.not()` call, so if you have an element with class "test" nested inside another one, it will be affected whether or not it already has class "updated".

I think your code really should just be like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('.test').not('.updated').addClass("updated");
}, 3000);
```

You don't need the `.each()` because `.addClass()` will do that for you.

*edit* — if you do need to do more work inside a `.each()`, your code would look like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('.test').not('.updated').each(function(){
                var $parentDiv = $(this).parent('div');
                // do something
                $(this).addClass("updated"); 
                //Above: change this element's status
        });
}, 3000);
```

Inside the `.each()` callback, `this` will be bound to each of the selected elements from the outer jQuery sequence: the set of elements that have class "test" but not class "updated".  If you use `$(".test")` *again* inside the `.each()` callback, that will start all over again and find all the elements with class "test" in the entire page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is my fault, I forget to say that , i want to dosomthing, after add updated class, so the loop is not only used to add class, I already change the question, so in this condition, do you know what is wrong?

Comment: @llyjy21 your code still has the same basic problem. Each call to `$(".test")` goes back to the *entire* DOM to find all of the elements with class "test".

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand now

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated function which should work use `$(this)` instead of `$('.test')` inside the each loop

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('.test').not('.updated').each(function(){
                var $parentDiv = $(this).parent('div');
                // do something
                $(this).addClass("updated"); 
                //Above: change this element's status
        });
}, 3000);
```

As you are referencing in the each `$('.test')` which is all the test class `.updated` or otherwise that is the reason the `.updated` class is still coming up in the loop

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.find()` which is used to select all descendants of that element.

> Refer [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Therefore, in your case, the scenario is class `.test` without class `.updated` will search in all its children to find class `.test` and it will add class `updated` to it. So, all the children whether or not they are having class `.updated`, `.updated` class will be added to it.

Hence, what you want to do can be simply achieved by this:

```
 $('.test').not('.updated').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("updated");
 });
```

or why not simply,

```
$('.test').not('.updated').addClass('updated');
```